# ui-route update url without param

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i'm trying to update url without params is it possible ? on my app i created state

```
.state('webPrint', {
    url: '/web/print/:lead',
    templateUrl: '/application/views/web-print.html'
})
```

and when i'm redirecting i'm passing an object

```
var obj = JSON.stringify(lead);
$state.go('webPrint', { lead: obj });
```

but my url is something should be like

`/web` to `/web/print` but it shows `/web/print + "stringify object data"` so i changed my code to

```
$state.go('webPrint', { lead: obj }, { location: false, inherit: false });
```

but now it's not change url at all. i mean `/web` to `/web`

how can i avoid stringify string on url and pass direct to new url?

thanks

Comment: First of all your state's url definition itself wrong. I edited it. Hope you accept this edit. you mentioned `but now it's not change url at all. i mean /web to /web` which means url is not changing from /web to /web. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: state definition accepted. but i just meant when i'm redirecting, state has changed but url doesn't. that's why i said should be `/web` to `/web/print` but when state change it'll `/web` to `/web`

Answer (score 0):

You are using option `location: false` which means you are telling not to change the url.

I would say create a service with getter and setter to save and retrieve  your data like below

```
angular.module('app.service').factory('leadService', function(){
    var lead = {};
    return{
        getLead : function(){
          return lead;
        },
        setLead: function(data){
          lead = data;
        }
   }
});

.state('webPrint', {
        url: '/web/print',
        templateUrl: '/application/views/web-print.html'
    })


var obj = JSON.stringify(lead);
leadService.setLead(obj);
$state.go('webPrint');
```

Then in your controller get the lead Object using

```
var lead = leadService.getLead();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. no i don't want to use a service for passing params. that would not be the solution to come up with ui-router. any way could you please undone that unnecessary edit on my post you made?

Comment: I have undone the edit which worried you much. But read again your post by yourself.